# ZeroMQ and Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, zeromq

What would be the recommended way of adding a ZeroMQ socket in a Sails.JS application.

Should I define a sails hook for dealing with the socket configuration and connection and have a global scoped socket object to use in the different controllers or is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're looking to do is set up a single ZeroMQ socket to serve the whole app, then using a custom Sails hook would be a very good solution.  Rather than making the socket object a global, you can either add it as a property of the hook (exposing it as `sails.hooks.zeromq.socket`, for example), or keep it scoped locally to the hook file and expose its methods via the hook (e.g. `sails.hooks.zeromq.send`, `sails.hooks.zeromq.on`).

Sails doesn't currently offer an easy way to share custom hooks across projects, but it's on our roadmap to implement a system much like what we currently have for *generators*, where you could add something like this to a `.sailsrc` file:

```
"hooks": {
    "zeromq": "path/to/zeromq/hook/code"
}
```

So, if you make a hook for ZeroMQ and open-source it, it could be a valuable resource for others!

There's not a ton of documentation out there right now for custom hooks, but there is this [riveting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3z8i8ByAXs) on YouTube that discusses the topic in some detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I followed the hook way and ended up having the desired functionality, although it isn't as generic as I would like. 

My need is pretty similar to store a JSON document in a NoSQL DB, but instead of directly sending to the DB I just need to push it to another ZeroMQ component. For this use case I'm starting to feel that maybe a Waterline adapter (with only a CREATE method) could fit better, with the added value of the model validations before the push (which I'm doing manually at this moment). Does it make sense?